# Error when registering CKEditor 5 in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor

Here's my code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block';
Vue.use( CKEditor );
```

It follows the example from the CKEditor documentation here, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html.  The only difference is that the documentation is loading the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue` build.

I am using the Laravel UI boilerplate, so that means NPM and Webpack.  The package builds fine, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a careless error.  The import for CKEditor should have been specific to VueJS, not to a particular editor build.  Here is the correct line:

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
```